# T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, types, clr, integration

I'm trying to create a custom SQL Function by CLR Integration but I'm having a T-SQL and CLR types mismatch error.

DLL:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

Public Class Encrypter_Decrypter
    <SqlFunction(DataAccess:=DataAccessKind.Read)> _
    Public Shared Function EncryptString(ByVal strItem As String)
        Dim strPassPhrase As String = "***********"
        Dim strInitVector As String = "***********"
        Dim objEncryption = New PCI.Encryption()
        objEncryption.Initialise(strPassPhrase, strInitVector, -1, -1, -1, "", "", 1)
        Dim EncryptedString As String = objEncryption.Encrypt(strItem)
        objEncryption = Nothing
        EncryptString = EncryptedString
    End Function
End Class
```

Creating the SQL Function:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY EncrypterDecrypter 
FROM 'c:\dll\Encrypter_Decrypter\Encrypter_Decrypter.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION EncryptString(@strItem NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS EXTERNAL NAME EncrypterDecrypter.Encrypter_Decrypter.EncryptString; 
GO
```

Error:

**CREATE FUNCTION for "EncryptString" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match.**

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing an `As String` from the end of your function definition:

```
Public Shared Function EncryptString(ByVal strItem As String) As String
```

And obviously don't have `Option Explicit` or `Option Strict` turned on (either of which would alert you to this problem). By default, the return type of a function is `Object`, which doesn't have a mapping to any SQL Server data type.

---

Not knowing what your encryption package does, it's also usually a bad plan to be storing the encrypted version as a string (unless your package is automatically doing e.g. Base64 encoding?)

Comment: Thank you so much Is working now :) Thanks for your advice too, the encryption package does everything automatically

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you missing a return type for the function?